# Is $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-3}]$ UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{-3}]$ UFD ? If so , why $$4=2 \times 2 = (1+\sqrt{-3}) \times (1-\sqrt{-3} )$$ and every terms are irreducible ?

Comment: Every PID is UFD, and in a PID every irreducible is prime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your suspicion is correct. On the other hand, the [integral closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_closure) of $\mathbf{Z}$ in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is the larger ring $\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}]$, since $-3 \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. This *is* norm-Euclidean and in particular a UFD. Note that all UFDs are integrally closed, so this is another way to see that $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ does not have unique factorization.

Comment: Thank you ! It's rather what I want .

Answer (score 6):

FYI, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not only not a UFD, but [it's the unique imaginary order of a quadratic ring of algebraic integers that has the half-factorial property](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~coykenda/paper6b.pdf) (Theorem 2.3)--ie any two factorizations of a nonzero nonunit have the same number of irreducibles.

Comment: interesting theorem ! thanks for your useful comment .

Comment: You're most welcome.